# Using python string wild cards within the field calculator ArcGIS 10.3.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, field-calculator, arcgis-10.3

I have two fields. One field has an ID. The other field has a list of ID's. Using the **Field Calculator** I with to calculate **1 or 0 if** either field **contain the same ID number**. I was successful at writing an arcpy row by row query, but there's millions or records and a linear test of rows is not efficient. I need to calculate it in one hit.

I need to take a field and make it's value a wild card and test the other field for that value. I have tried the "*" and "in" methods. But it's not returning the correct value.

Can someone assist me in why this is wrong?

[image]

**Code One:**

```
def myCal(reportnumber,spatialjoin):
 reportnumbercheck = ('*'+(str(reportnumber))+'*')
 if (reportnumbercheck in spatialjoin):
  return 1
 else:
  return 0
```

Comment: Why doesn't `reportnumber in spatialjoin` work?  There is no wildcard in check like that in Python.

Comment: Ah ha. I had included the wild card in the "in" method...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should just work as a normal string `in` check

```
def myCal(reportnumber, spatialjoin):
 if reportnumber in spatialjoin:
  return 1
 else:
  return 0
```

or even one like:

```
def myCal(reportnumber, spatialjoin):
   return 1 if reportnumber in spatialjoin else 0
```

Answer (score 1):

i haven't tested it, but you may not need the wildcards at all - if you convert the value in the spatial join field to a list - something like

```
def myCal(reportnumber,spatialjoin):
    #spatialjoin = spatialjoin.split(';')
    if reportnumber in spatialjoin:
        return(1)
    else:
        return(0)
```

heck, may not even need to convert spatial join to a list...
indeed, no list conversion needed - i'll comment out that part...